# where should PostgresSQL 'WHERE' go in aggregation?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

The following postgres query works:

```
dvdrental=# SELECT title, COUNT(title) AS c FROM film          
JOIN inventory
ON film.film_id = inventory.film_id GROUP BY film.title LIMIT 5;

      title       | c 
------------------+---
 Academy Dinosaur | 8
 Ace Goldfinger   | 3
 Adaptation Holes | 4
 Affair Prejudice | 7
 African Egg      | 3
(5 rows)

Time: 1.671 ms
```

Then if I want to restrict say lest the films with a specific number of copies in the inventory or count how many films have a certain number in the inventory a starting point is this:

```
dvdrental=# SELECT title, COUNT(title) AS c FROM film
JOIN inventory
ON film.film_id = inventory.film_id GROUP BY film.title WHERE c = 4;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE"
LINE 3: ...m.film_id = inventory.film_id GROUP BY film.title WHERE c = ...
                                                             ^
Time: 0.337 ms
```

..but it does not work.

I have tried every possible position for the `WHERE c = 4` here and it will not work. Have a feeling that it would have worked if it were MySQL rather than PostgresSQL.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Hint:  `HAVING`.

Comment: Section order: `select` - `from` - `where` - `group by` - `having` - `order by`. There are other sections but those are the most common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it would be `having` instead of `where`

```
    SELECT title, COUNT(title) AS c FROM film
    JOIN inventory
    ON film.film_id = inventory.film_id     
    GROUP BY film.title 
    having COUNT(title)=4
```

The `HAVING` clause used for aggregate function

Comment: Thanks. Just had to add the semicolon. I had forgotten that, has been a while, and now I think that it is the same in MySQL, this was not really a postgres peculiarity. WHERE when no aggregation, HAVING when _yes_ aggregation, probably in both postgres and mysql.

Comment: @cardamom for all dbms having is applied for aggregate function

Comment: Thanks @ZaynulAbadinTuhin. How come you can't put `having c=4;` I tried that and it didn't work. You have given `COUNT(title)` an alias 'c' as I understand so should be able to use that again later..

Comment: @cardamom alias does not support all dbms in where or having clause as a result it thrown error

Answer (score 1):

> If You want to use C column in where clause then can use below query also.

```
WITH title_query 
  AS
  (
        SELECT title, COUNT(title) AS c FROM film
        JOIN inventory
        ON film.film_id = inventory.film_id     
        GROUP BY film.title
  ) 
  SELECT * FROM title_query WHERE C= 4
```